# Caching generic data in a dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, caching, dictionary

I have an application which caches some data at startup. There are several things to put in a cache, but they are very similar. I created classes like this, the only difference in them is the type of the item to be added to the dictionary (in this example the Setting class), and the _sqlNotifyCommand.CommandText.

```
public class SettingsCache : ILoggerClass
{
    private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Setting>> _cachedItems;
    private string _entityConnectionString;
    private SQLNotifier _sqlNotifier;
    private SqlCommand _sqlNotifyCommand = new SqlCommand();
    private bool _dataLoaded = false;

    private void AddItem(Setting item)
    {
        if (!_cachedItems.ContainsKey(item.PartnerId))
        {
            _cachedItems.Add(item.PartnerId, new Dictionary<int, Setting>());
        }
        if (_cachedItems[item.PartnerId].ContainsKey(item.Id))
        {
            _cachedItems[item.PartnerId].Remove(item.Id);
        }
        _cachedItems[item.PartnerId].Add(item.Id, item);
    }

    public Setting GetSetting(int partnerId, int id)
    {
        if (_cachedItems.ContainsKey(partnerId))
        {
            if (_cachedItems[partnerId].ContainsKey(id))
            {
                return _cachedItems[partnerId][id];
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public SettingsCache(string connectionString)
    {
        _entityConnectionString = connectionString;

        _cachedItems = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Setting>>();

        LoadData();

        try
        {
            using (var db = new partnerEntity(connectionString))
            {
                string adoSqlConnectionString = ((EntityConnection) db.Connection).StoreConnection.ConnectionString;

                _sqlNotifier = new SQLNotifier(adoSqlConnectionString);
                _sqlNotifier.NewMessage += _sqlNotifier_NewMessage;


                _sqlNotifyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                _sqlNotifyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT setting_id, setting_value, partner_id FROM dbo.setting";
                _sqlNotifyCommand.Notification = null;

                _sqlNotifier.RegisterDependency(_sqlNotifyCommand);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            this.Log(this, LogLevel.Error, 0, exception);
        }
    }

    private void _sqlNotifier_NewMessage(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Insert || e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Update)
        {
            this.Log(this, LogLevel.Info, 0, string.Format("Database changed, reloading settings data..."));
            LoadData();
        }
        _sqlNotifier.RegisterDependency(_sqlNotifyCommand);
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        _dataLoaded = false;
        try
        {
            using (var db = new partnerEntity(_entityConnectionString))
            {
                var dbData = db.setting.ToList();

                foreach (var cItem in dbData)
                {
                    AddItem(new Setting
                    {
                        PartnerId = cItem.partner_id,
                        Id = cItem.setting_id,
                        Value = cItem.setting_value
                    });
                }
            }
            _dataLoaded = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            this.Log(this, LogLevel.Error, 0, exception);
        }
        if (!_dataLoaded)
        {
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).ContinueWith(_ => { LoadData(); });
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more generic way to do this? The last thing which was needed in the classes this part:

```
            if (!_dataLoaded)
        {
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).ContinueWith(_ => { LoadData(); });
        }
```

And I had to modify every Caching class. I needed to declare the variable, add it to the try-catch block, and after the block insert the same line in 6 classes. This code seems very boilerplate to me, I can't believe there is no simpler solution. I tried to make an Interface with AddItem, LoadData, OnLoadDataFailed methods, but in the AddItem method I need to specify the item, I'm stuck.

Comment: Have you read up on Generics? Seems like that would solve the issue of having the same class with the only difference being the type it caches.

Comment: Yep, but I can't figure out how to declare a Dictionary with a generic type, and after that the AddItem method is still there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic structure of what (I think) you want to accomplish using Generics.

First, declare a common interface for cached items so that the `AddItem` method still works:

```
public interface ICacheItem
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int PartnerId { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can create the `SettingsCache<T>` that holds the items:

```
public class SettingsCache<T> : ILogger where T : ICacheItem
{
    private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, T>> _cachedItems;
    //...

    public SettingsCache(string connectionString, string commandText)
    {
        //...
    }

    private void AddItem(T item)
    {
        if (!_cachedItems.ContainsKey(item.PartnerId))
        {
            _cachedItems.Add(item.PartnerId, new Dictionary<int, T>());
        }
        if (_cachedItems[item.PartnerId].ContainsKey(item.Id))
        {
            _cachedItems[item.PartnerId].Remove(item.Id);
        }
        _cachedItems[item.PartnerId].Add(item.Id, item);
    }
}
```

I left out most of the implementation to focus on your two biggest concerns, the command text and the `AddItem` method. The generic has a constraint so that it can only accept items that are of `ICacheItem`, so you can use any properties that `ICacheItem` defines.

To use a cache, simply create one with the specific type (assuming `Setting` implements `ICacheItem`):

```
var settingsCache = new SettingsCache<Setting>("connection string", "command string");
```